# User can Sell products just like amazon in magento

Tags: magento, product

I am working on one magento site.Now i need to set products for sell just like `half.com` or `amazon.com` , where user can sell his products.Simply means reselling.Is there any clue which can help me.I don't know from where i take start.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**there is a one free extension available for that**

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer-s-products.html

*Note:: i am not sure how look like this because I haven't used it,*

Comment: why you removed other one's ? i like the extension and will try.

Comment: because others are paid version so

Comment: Means there is no default function or method that can help in this issue ?

Comment: no default magento wont provide this type of functionality,,but you can use this extension and its free version